# Reading remote file size using filesize

Tags: php, filesize, remote-access

I read the manual that [filesize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php) is able to calculate file size from remote file.
However, when I try to do that with snippet below. I got error `PHP Warning:  filesize(): stat failed for http://someserver/free_wallpaper/jpg/0000122_480_320.jpg in /tmp/test.php on line 5`

Here's my snippet:

```
$file = "http://someserver/free_wallpaper/jpg/0000122_480_320.jpg";
echo filesize( $file );
```

> Turns out, I can't use HTTP for
>   filesize(). Case close. I'll use
>   snippet [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php#92462) as a work-around
>   solution.

Comment: There's a shorter work-around: get_headers( $file_url, 1 ) will give you an array that will (hopefully) have a key "Content-length" whose value is the filesize in bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`filesize` doesn't work for HTTP - it depends on `stat`, which [isn't supported for the HTTP(S) protocol](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.http.php).

The PHP man page for filesize says:

`Refer to List of Supported Protocols/Wrappers for a listing of which wrappers support stat() family of functionality.`

This doesn't mean every protocol/wrapper works "out of the box" with `filesize`. You could always get around that by doing a full GET of the remote URL and calculating the size of the data you get back, of if you can get a Content-Length header you could try a HEAD request to avoid transferring the file data.

Answer (score 1):

You can get file size of web url using below code

function getFileSize($file){

```
   $ch = curl_init($file);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

   $data = curl_exec($ch);
   curl_close($ch);
   $contentLength=0;
   if (preg_match('/Content-Length: (\d+)/', $data, $matches)) {
       $contentLength = (int)$matches[1];

   }
   return $contentLength; }
```

Comment: Getting different numbers... can u explain why??... i.e: `$ch = curl_init('http://www.ehow.co.uk/ui/en-gb/ehow.png');/// outputs: 11402` and `$ch = curl_init('http://www.ehow.co.uk/ui/en-gb/ehow.pngjavascript:alert(1);');//outputs: 45821` and `$ch = curl_init('http://www.ehow.co.uk/ui/en-gb/wrong_path_/'); //outputs: 45820` and  `$ch = curl_init('http://www.ehow.co.uk/ui/');outputs: 233` ..... This makes it difficult to know which number means what... more so, difficult **to correctly read the remote file size**.... Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you read that.  `filesize` requires `stat`, and based on the [`HTTP wrapper`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.http.php) page, I don't think it supports `stat` on any version of PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to investigate using [http_head()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-head.php). I think the snippet you reference downloads the file to determine the file size, which may not be necessary. If the web server you are referencing sends back accurate header information, you should be able to determine file-size, date-modified and several other useful identifying features.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the remote picture size, try using [`getimagesize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php)