# Get sizes of uploaded files with php

Tags: php, file-upload

After i upload some files to my server, and save them in sql, i list them on my site.

```
while($a = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_files))
        {
            $path_parts = pathinfo($a['fajl_file']);
            $extension = $path_parts['extension'];

            $path = $host.'/documents/'.$a['fajl_file'];

            echo '<tr>
                <td>'.html($a['fajl_nev']).'</td>
                <td>'.date_substr($a['fajl_datetime']).'</td>
                <td>'.$extension.'</td>
                <td>'.filesize($path).'</td>
                <td class="table_text_center">
                    <a class="table_delete_link delete_data" id="" href="#"><i class="fa fa-download"></i></a>
                </td>
            </tr>';
        }
```

Where i am listing the files, i want to display not just the name or upload date, i want the file size also.

With this code, i get this error:

> Warning:  filesize(): stat failed for

When i check the website source, the path i gived, its correct. The files are in the documents folder on the server.

Comment: Make sure you are passing Directory path  in `$path`. If `$path` consist `url` then you will not get size

Comment: What do you mean? Sorry i dont understand. Can you write an example?

Comment: will you show what is your `$path` contain?

Comment: It gives back the full url, domain, folder, and the file. It is correct, i can open it also.

Comment: you have to use the filepath and not the url.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225852/reading-remote-file-size-using-filesize

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you are passing an absolute URL to the [`filesize()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php) when it needs a relative local file link (Qualifier: *Some URLs are valid in PHP5+*).

```
   $path = $host.'/documents/'.$a['fajl_file'];
   /*** 
   /*  http://www.someweb.site/documents/somefile.pdf
   /***/
   echo '<td>'.filesize($path).'</td>';
```

The above is passing to output `filesize("http://www.someweb.site/documents/somefile.pdf")` which is not what you want, you need to translate the document path to the ***local*** file version

You can do this using `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`:

```
   $path = $host.'/documents/'.$a['fajl_file'];
   $localPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/documents/'.$a['fajl_file'];
   /*** 
   /*  /home/users/webaccount/www/documents/somefile.pdf
   /***/
   echo '<td>'.filesize($localPath).'</td>';
```

This should then output the data requested.

- You may well want to [format your file size output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501427/php-filesize-mb-kb-conversion).
- Please also read [**This excellent answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3225864/3536236).

Answer (score 0):

Use the filepath for the filesize() function.

example filepath:

```
/var/www/myfile.txt
```

or on Windows

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\myfile.txt
```

Comment: Im sorry, but i dont understand this.